# callback function not executed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, get

I was learning to send a get request in jquery. The following is the block of code which makes the get request. I checked in my servlet that the get request was made successfully but the callback function was not invoked. I can't figure out the problem.

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/PC_controlo/StatusServlet?id=1001',
function(data){
alert('hello');
});
```

And the browsers network tab shows this

```
[01:21:26.759] GET http://localhost:8080/PC_controlo/StatusServlet?id=1001 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1ms]
```

+

This is what I have done in my servlet.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write("Working");
            out.close();
```

and .fail(msg){ alert('Failed with message:'+JSON.stringify(msg)); gave the following message

```
Failed with message: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: did you check the console? i expect to see a same-origin error.

Comment: Do you see a response in the network tab of the developer tools in chrome (or whatever browser you use)?

Comment: @dhsto Yes I see a response, and I have edited my question as well.

Comment: Does the content of the response contain what you expect?

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes everything seems fine in the console. But the code is acting funny :/

Comment: Based on what you're seeing in the console, you should be also seeing an alert. odd.

Comment: I see you updated your question with the failed message. A status of 0 usually indicates that you are doing cross-site scripting where access is denied. Remember that AJAX requests are limited to the same domain name only. Is that the case here? I see you are making a request to localhost, is the code also being loaded on the localhost domain, or something else?

Comment: @Brian No my html code is not on localhost. Its in my home folder. I just wrote the code to test my server.

Comment: Sorry still need some clarification. Wherever you call that code, it must be on the same domain or you will have issues. So if you load the AJAX via HTML on somedomain.com, it must be using a .get to somedomain.com. Are you doing that? Is the .get domain you are trying to load exactly the same domain that you are loading the HTML from? If not make that the same and I suspect your problem will be resolved.

Comment: @Brian Thanks buddy. Figured out the issue. My html wasn't on the same domain. Would you please post your previous comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I did a few tests with replacing the URL with Google.com, and I encountered the same problem. I noticed if you use .done(), .always(), and .error(), you might have better luck figuring out exactly what is going on. Check out this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gQfsd/

```
$.get('http://www.google.com/')
.done(function(data) {
    alert('Success! Data loaded: ' + data);   
})
.fail(function(msg) {
    alert('Failed with message: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
})
.always(function() {
    alert('Always Alerts');
});
```

Comment: If you check the console, you'll see a very obvious `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `

Comment: I was just using this as an example if he wants to see what is going on via his alerts instead of using the console, since that is what the OP was using.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that your request did not complete successfully, so your *success* handler function callback is not called, because there was no success.

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) `$.get`'s success handler function is: (emphasis mine)

> A callback function that is executed *if the request succeeds.*

To get more control over the error handling of the AJAX request, It's usually recommended to use `$.ajax` instead, which you can [read the documentation for here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This will allow you to use an `error` callback that will trigger when the request wont complete for some reason.

`$.get` is just a shortcut method that delegates to `$.ajax` under the covers.

---

Why is your request failing?  No clue.  That's between your browser and the server you are talking to.  It could be a million things.  Check the network tab of your browser development console and see what the request and response looks like.

Comment: There's no need to jump to using `$.ajax()` for that reason. You can just as easily use deferred methods, like `.done()` and `.fail()` on the promise that `$.get()` returns; there's nothing special about `$.ajax()` in that sense

Comment: It's a stylistic debate, but I think that in all but the simplest cases `$.ajax` is the better choice, as it makes it very clear how the request is setup.  And when you run into the limits of the `$.get` convenience method, it's easier to customize that request.  Maybe I'm just old school :p

Comment: I 100% agree with you. I hate using shortcut methods, like `$.get`, `$.post`, `.click(func)` (instead of `.on("click", func)`) and I don't know why. I was just saying that I didn't think your reasoning for changing to `$.ajax()` was right - I don't think it has any "better" error handling is all.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a communication error with the call itself, or the call failed for some reason. Check  for failures too:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/PC_controlo/StatusServlet?id=1001')
 .success(function(result) {alert('success'); })
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(textStatus) });
```

Comment: but this stuff works
<form method="get" action="http://localhost:8080/PC_controlo/StatusServlet">
<input type = "hidden" value=1001 name = "id">
<input type = "submit"/>
I get the required string as the output

Comment: .success and .error should actually be .done and .fail. .success and .error are depreciated and will be removed in newer versions of jQuery (if it isn't already).

Comment: @AshwinSurana using the <form> working is irrelevant, <form> isn't subject to the same origin policy and doesn't require the data to be in any specific format.